# Splitting csv by few rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with a few rows header. Next I got a sample(1) data, and next again is header and sample(2) data. The number of samples (and headers) are not constant in files.

DF looks like this:

```
[header]
InfoMap : 4214
InfoSample:3122
Content:,   ,22dmm
Sample_name, Sample_id, Sample_phone, Sample_project
Ana           22          785             a6659
Ana           22          785             a658141
Ana           22          785             csd449
Ben           23          756             a6659
Ben           23          756             a658141
Charlie       44          733             c658141
[header]
InfoMap : 423421
InfoSample:315
Content,   ,562dmm
Sample_name, Sample_id, Sample_phone, Sample_project
Cris           82          7835             a6659
Cris           82          7485             a658141
Cris           82          7485             csd449
MATT           53          268              a6659
MATT           53          268              a658141
Dan            42          885              c658141
```

What I tried to do:
I need to split each header with sample to new file. So in case above I should got 2 files:

file1:

```
[header]
InfoMap : 4214
InfoSample:3122
Content:,   ,22dmm
Sample_name, Sample_id, Sample_phone, Sample_project
Ana           22          785             a6659
Ana           22          785             a658141
Ana           22          785             csd449
Ben           23          756             a6659
Ben           23          756             a658141
Charlie       44          733             c658141
```

file2:

```
[header]
InfoMap : 423421
InfoSample:315
Content,   ,562dmm
Sample_name, Sample_id, Sample_phone, Sample_project
Cris           82          7835             a6659
Cris           82          7485             a658141
Cris           82          7485             csd449
MATT           53          268              a6659
MATT           53          268              a658141
Dan            42          885              c658141
```

How can I do it in the simplest way in pandas or core Python? As I said numbers of headers and samples are not constant.

I tried it by loop for:

- Looking for [header] in line
- save the numbers of all [header] lines index numbers.
- with "open" I tried to save all compartments to new files

The problem was: I can't read it as csv because it was one column dataframe (because headers), line was read in a weird way because I have files with mixed samples.

I'm looking for a better concep. Maybe Pandas has some functions I don't know about. If not, I'll keep going with my way of doing things and try to do it this way.

I'm not necessarily looking for a ready-made solution, but some hints or concepts.

Comment: please share what code you have tried already. Using python CSV module read the csv file , then loop through each row,save row data in a list and check for the count of "InfoMap" if the count greater than 1 or the last row is reached  then write the list into another csv file name file1, file2 ... filen_N

Comment: Added psuedocode coz I deleted my conceptions. It didint works.

Comment: If you are working with large files, it may worth writing data directly into the destination file instead of storing into an intermediate list. That way you won't add load on your memory. With small files this is irrelevant though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the psuedocode sample code according to the logic I have given in the comment assuming that "InfoMap" is the starting point of header:

```
dataList = []
with open('YourData.csv', newline='') as File:  
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        dataList = []
        count = 0
        for row in reader:
            if "InfoMap" in row[0]:
                count += 1
                if count > 1:
                    #fileName = "file" + str(count)
                    #WriteDataListToCSV(dataList, fileName) create a function that can write dataList into csv 
                    #print(dataList)
                    dataList = []
                    dataList.append(row)
                else:
                    dataList.append(row)
            else:
                dataList.append(row)
        #fileName = "file" + str(count)
        #WriteDataListToCSV(dataList)  
        #print(dataList)
```

You can uncomment the print statements to see what dataList contains

Answer (score 0):

Another psedocode (or buggy real code). Only variation is  that you don't write the data into a list.

```
file_no = 0
write_file = open(f"sub_file_{file_no}.csv", "a+")
with open("input.csv") as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "[header]":
            # At the start of a new file. Close the old, increment count, open new
            write_file.close()
            file_no += 1
            write_file = open(f"sub_file_{file_no}.csv", "a+")
        # Just pass current row into the currently open file
        write_file.write(row)
write_file.close()
```